# How can I make a freezer?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic-items

I'm going to the Elemental Plane of Fire, and I don't want my ice cream to melt. What's the least expensive and most portable method to keep my ice cream consistently intact?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. I edited this question so that it better adheres to the site's guidelines. I hope that's okay. Thank you for an interesting question and have fun.

Comment: That's alright. In fact cheapest would be great!

Comment: Closing this for the time being as opinion based.  All the answers are a) "brainstorms" with no validation to them (exception for the brown mold one), and b) obviously not really up for the plane of fire, as "a box" is going to burn there. Maybe some retooling of the question can yield more solid answers.

Comment: @mxyzplk Those sound like great reasons to downvote the answers that you don't like rather than reasons to put the question on hold. Or am I missing some nuance?

Comment: When most of the answers are bad, the question must need help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the most powerful spell in the history of Pathfinder!

[**Prestidigitation!**](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/prestidigitation.html)

That spell allows you to chill 1 pound of non-living material.

If your GM allows it, using the custom magic item rules, you could make a box which would be permanently affected by the prestidigitation spell for as much as 1000 GP!

Prestidigitation would then be a permanent effect chilling the inner part of the "fridge" allowing it to chill all of the box's contents!

Comment: That's a good idea actually. Is it able to be ups called/strengthened though? I have a feeling that my Gm would probably say it's not strong enough to keep icecream solid on the plane of fire based off the spell's description.

Comment: @Chirpas Unfortunatly, I doubt it. Prestidigitation is meant to be weak. But if you select a good material for the inner layer, you should be good. A thin aluminium layer for example.

Comment: I'll have to ask my Gm, thanks for the answer!

Comment: For 2,500 gp, anybody can employ the spell *prestidigitation* at will with one of my favorite magic items, the [*cloak of the hedge wizard*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/c-d/cloak-of-the-hedge-wizard/). (The transmutation version is especially (*ahem*) cool.)

Answer (score 6):

A box of sawdust.

"the ice was covered with sawdust. Ice was delivered to as far away as India"

https://insulation.org/io/articles/a-history-of-refrigeration/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_house_(building)

Comment: Not sure that would work well on the plane of fire with the low flashpoint of sawdust (118 - 147 Degrees Celsius depending on the wood), but it is a very interesting background on refrigeration, and could likely augment other answers.

Answer (score 6):

**Brown mold in an unbreakable container**

[Brown Mold](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/traps-hazards-and-special-terrains/hazards/special-hazards/brown-mold-cr-2/) removes heat, so use it to shield your ice cream.

Your only challenge is to put it in a container that won't rupture when the mold tries to grow uncontrollably on the elemental plane of fire.

Answer (score 3):

Seal some [Brown Mold](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/traps-hazards-and-special-terrains/hazards/special-hazards/brown-mold-cr-2/) in a container and put that container inside a larger, insulated container for your ice cream.  The cost is the cost of the containers plus the cost of the brown mold (free if you can find it and harvest it).

That's a trick I've been using since 2ndE (the walk in freezers had a ring of warmth on a hook outside it).  In this case, the freezer was double walled with the mold sandwiched between.  When a friend wanted their own freezer, I had him build a similar room, took some mold from mine, put it in between the walls of his and launched a couple of fireballs into it.  It was chilly in no time.

Comment: +1, but "fire brought within 5 feet of a brown mold causes it to instantly double in size" -- isn't this a safety hazard?

Comment: @DanB,  Either make a strong inner container or make it a 10' cube with the inner container suspended in the center.  That would be hard to transport without a portable hole.  On the freezer side, mine had a sign outside it that read:  Danger Brown Mold, idiots with fire will be thawed out and fed to my pets.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Léon's answer, though without requiring knowledge of the Prestidigitation spell, you can simply have your players encounter a merchant selling a "bag of colding" (or have them be given one by the quest giver).

I first heard of this concept while watching the Critical Role 5E (née Pathfinder) series of D&D on YouTube/Twitch. During one episode, the party was given a container that acted as a moderate refrigerator by a quest giver, in order to go kill a beast and harvest certain organs, in order to return said organs in exchange for a bounty, with the critical proviso that the organs still had to be fresh (the beast was many days' travel away in each direction).

You could have the questgiver require the container be returned after the quest into the Fire Plane, or have it last only long enough for them to complete their quest before the enchantment wears out. Any combination of criteria that result in 'limited effectiveness' are available to you as DM.